# Why Win7 search cannot find filename containing a substring

Tags: windows, search

I'm using Windows 7.

For example, I have a file named `a_ab.csv`. When I press `Ctrl+F`, the search starts. I type in `b`, then nothing is found. Only when I type in `ab` can I find the file `a_ab.csv`. Why?

Thank you all for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here. I found the solution from https://superuser.com/questions/447469/search-for-a-substring-in-file-name-with-built-in-windows-search. Put `*` at front of your search strings.

Comment: Oh great !! Thank you!